# How to have one React component take up entire screen (on all devices) until you scroll down?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So lets say I have 3 components: Header, Intro, and MainContent

if I have something like:

```
<div className='homepage'>
    <div id='top'>
        <Header />
        <Intro />
    </div>
    <div id='bottom'>
        <MainContent />
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I be able to style this so that the header and the intro take up the entirety of the screen on load, and then you have to scroll to reach the MainContent component?

I could I just set bottom padding of the #top to a percentage but that doesn't work for every device, correct?

Comment: You should be able to solve this React-agnostic. It sounds to me like you want `.top` to have 100% of the height. I'd remove it from `.homepage` (lift it in DOM until it is a child of `body`, set the height to 100% for `.top` and `html, body`

Comment: Applied this to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c2de97y6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `vh` units with Flexbox to easily achieve this. The basic idea is to give the `#top` a height of `100vh` (the full height of the viewport), and then use Flexbox to have the `<Intro />` fill the remaining space not taken up by the `<Header />`. Like this:

```css
#top {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.intro {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Styling CSS - not relevant to solving the issue */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.intro {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.header,
.intro,
.main {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#bottom {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div className='homepage'>
    <div id='top'>
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="intro">Intro</div>
    </div>
    <div id='bottom'>
        <div class="main">Main Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @johntc121Yes, you can use them together nicely.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I will give this a try in the morning and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Great, and don't forget to accept the solution that solves your issue ;)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!